# Wordpress (Pods) oEmbed Items

Tags: wordpress, iframe, oembed, podscms

I'm using the fantastic Pods plugin to extend Wordpress's basic content types with a few custom ones. I've build an advanced custom type which means I don't get the automatic oEmbed support built into the native page/post types. I've structured it so my custom content type has a pod page using a PHP page template and I have the oEmbed option enabled for my WYISWYG fields that can embed videos.

I found [this post](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/filter-hook-for-built-in-oembed-providers-eg-youtube) which seems to indicate that a basic `apply_filter` function should automatically handle any embeds but I can't seem to get it to work. I'm a bit new to filters. The code I tried is below:

```
<?php
// Fetch body field content from $pods object
$mycontent = $pods->field('field_body');
$output = apply_filters('oembed_dataparse', $mycontent);
echo $output;
?>
```

I tried a variety of different filters such as `the_content` and others but none seemed to work. I believe it may be a scoping/conflict issue with Pod pages since even writing out entire iFrame embed code into the template won't work but only displays an empty iFrame. The global oembed function does the same, i.e.

```
$videourl = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ';
$htmlcode = wp_oembed_get($videourl);
echo $htmlcode;
```

In the context of the page template will output:

```
<iframe width="500" height="375" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ?feature=oembed">
    <html>
        <head>
        </head>
        <body>
        </body>
    </html>
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

field() gets the value of the field, display() gets the output of the field (ran through any related filters / functions the field is configured to run through).

```
$mycontent = $pods->field('field_body');
```

should be

```
$mycontent = $pods->display('field_body');
```

For more information, see http://pods.io/docs/field/ vs http://pods.io/docs/display/

Comment: Was this ever resolved? I thought I saw it fixed in a recent patch but `display` on a WYSIWYG field still doesn't seem to output Youtube embeds correctly. I'm using advanced custom types if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `apply_filters('oembed_dataparse', $mycontent)` is incorrect since this meant to add functionality for processing other data types (photo, video etc) not catered for by default. What you want to do is mimic how WordPress does the embedding. I haven't tested the code below, but it seems to me the way to go about triggering the embed functionality:

```
global $wp_embed;

$mycontent = $pods->field('field_body');

$output = $wp_embed->autoembed($mycontent);

echo $output;
```

Comment: Thanks but I think the image might be in how the pod page is rendered. Normal Youtube `<iframe>` embeds load empty when written out in full in the template while `<object>` embeds work for some reason. Unless there's a way to use `autoembed` to generate objects this won't help even if it does convert the URLs to embeds.

Comment: The rendered iframe should be blank. Use a self-closing iframe tag and see what the results are. I just tested youtube embed and the resulting iframe is something like <iframe ... some properties ... />

Comment: Ok so I was fooling around with using a template stored in the Pods template section and other ways of generating the page content and now, suddenly, iFrames (hardcoded and generated by Wordpress) are working again!? However your code above doesn't seem to be processing the URLs in the body. Is it ok to use it in the middle of a Pod Page template? (I have a page template in the admin set up to point to a PHP template in my theme folder)

Comment: The code can work anywhere so long as you are passing it text that contains embedable urls.

Comment: Using the above code doesn't work even when I do `$mycontent = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ';` directly.

Comment: Then it must be something about the structure of the templates since I've just tested your modification and it worked. Try echoing the link (or any other text) directly without processing it and see if it appears. If it shows up then perhaps there's further processing being done by the template that interferes with the output.

Comment: The links have always been showing up. All the solutions I've tried output the field with all the URLs still in it, just unprocessed. The above code does work in my WP page templates, just not in my custom Pod page templates.